# How to pass multiple arguments to golang net rpc call

Tags: go, rpc

I am using net library in go and I want to make RPC call:

```
Client.Call("action", []string{"arg1", "arg2"}, &response)
```

But in JSON I see:

```
{"method":"action","params":[["arg1","arg2"]],"id":0}
```

Notice that arguments are enclosed with double square brackets.

In my case I need params to be a simple list:

```
{"method":"action","params":["arg1","arg2"],"id":0}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codec that Go's JSON RPC uses on top of the `rpc.Client` will take whatever param you send and encode that as the first element of the array it uses for the params.

So the encoded request will always have a top level array with just one element, which will contain the params you sent, as you already noted.

See the `WriteRequest` function here:

https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/jsonrpc/client.go#L57

To achieve what you want, you can implement a custom `rpc.ClientCodec`.

The interface is documented here:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#ClientCodec

You can borrow almost all of the implementation for the default JSON codec here:

https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/jsonrpc/client.go

And modify the `params` attribute of the request to read:

```
Params interface{} `json:"params"`
```

Then when writing your `WriteRequest` based on the standard one, you can just assign your params to the request params:

```
c.req.Params[0] = param
```

You can then use the `rpc.NewClientWithCodec` to create a client using your custom codec:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#NewClientWithCodec

Comment: Thanks. I dug up to the place where I saw the c.req.Params[0] = param line and saw its 8 years old.